# Haskell extensible effects: effect in another effect

Tags: haskell, extensible

I'm trying to use `extensible-skeleton` package.
Stacking an effect in another effect results compile error.
I tried some other language extensions and type annotations but could not remove these errors.
How to resolve these errors?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Main where

import Data.Extensible
import Data.Extensible.Effect
import Data.Type.Equality

type In0 effs = Lookup effs "io" IO
type In1 effs = Lookup effs "reader-float" (ReaderEff Double)

run0 :: forall a. Eff '["io" >: IO] a -> IO a
run0 = retractEff

run1 :: forall effs a. Double -> Eff (("reader-float" >: ReaderEff Double) ': effs) a -> Eff effs a
run1 x = peelEff0 pure $ \Refl k -> k x

lift0 :: forall effs a. In0 effs => IO a -> Eff effs a
lift0 = liftEff (Proxy :: Proxy "io")

ask1 :: forall effs. In1 effs => Eff effs Double
ask1 = askEff (Proxy :: Proxy "reader-float")

eff0 :: forall effs. In0 effs => Eff effs ()
eff0 = do
  lift0 $ print "eff0"
  run1 2.5 eff1

eff1 :: forall effs. (In0 effs, In1 effs) => Eff effs ()
eff1 = do
  x <- ask1
  lift0 $ print "eff1"
  lift0 $ print (floor x)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  run0 eff0
```

errors at compile time:

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Main
app/Main.hs:32:12: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘membership-0:Type.Membership.Internal.Elaborate
                             "io" (membership-0:Type.Membership.Internal.FindAssoc 1 "io" effs)’
                     with ‘'membership-0:Type.Membership.Internal.Expecting (n0 ':> IO)’
        arising from a use of ‘eff1’
      The type variable ‘n0’ is ambiguous
    • In the second argument of ‘run1’, namely ‘eff1’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: run1 2.5 eff1
      In the expression:
        do lift0 $ print "eff0"
           run1 2.5 eff1
    • Relevant bindings include
        eff0 :: Eff effs () (bound at app/Main.hs:30:1)
   |
32 |   run1 2.5 eff1
   |            ^^^^
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `run1` (which is already available as `runReaderEff`, by the way) accepts an effect whose outermost layer is `"reader-float"`, but the effect `eff1` that you're trying to `run1` only satisfies `In1 effs`, which guarantees `"reader-float"` is in there somewhere, but not necessarily at the outermost layer.

This reflects the fact that you can't run an arbitrary layer buried in the stack.  You need to run the layers from the outside-in.

What does work is constructing an explicit effect stack for `eff1` and then upcasting:

```
eff0 :: forall effs. In0 effs => Eff effs ()
eff0 = do
  lift0 $ print "eff0"
  castEff $ run1 2.5 (eff1 :: Eff '["reader-float" :> ReaderEff Double, "io" :> IO] ())
```

It might seem like you want to prepend `"reader-float"` to the `effs` for `eff0` and so write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

eff0 :: forall effs. In0 effs => Eff effs ()
eff0 = do
  lift0 $ print "eff0"
  castEff $ run1 2.5 (eff1 :: Eff (("reader-float" :> ReaderEff Double) ': effs) ())
```

but this doesn't work.  However, if you think about it for a bit, there's no reason to run `eff1` here in anything other than the specific `["reader-float", "io"]` stack.

Remember, the reason for having general `effs` in the type signatures for `eff0` and `eff1` is to let them be used in any effects stack with their required layers; the general type signatures are for the benefit of the caller.  In this case, `eff0` is calling `eff1`, and it has no reason to supply `eff1` with anything other than the layers it needs, the new `"reader-float"` layer that it constructs locally, and the "io" layer that it casts into its own general `effs` environment.  There's nothing else in `effs` of interest to `eff0` or `eff1`, so no need to propagate `effs` down from `eff0` to `eff1`.

Comment: Second code snippet is what I want to do. Is it impossible to propagate `effs` down from `eff0` to `eff1` without explicit effect stack? For example, define `In2`, `ask2` and `run2` as the same manner with `"reader-int"`. `eff2 = (ask1 >>= (lift0 . print)) >> (ask2 >>= (lift0 . print))` and `eff1 = ask1 >>= (\x -> run2 (floor x) eff2)`. This case needs to propagate `effs` down from `eff1` to `eff2`.

Comment: Then `eff1` should call `eff2` with the explicit stack `["reader-int", "reader-float", "io"]`, supplying `reader-int` via `runReaderEff` and casting `["reader-float", "io"]` to its `effs`.  You will never be in a situation where you "need" unspecified `effs` from a calling effect.